# Is there a way to show a layout when open it's implement code in eclipse adt such as assistant editor of xcode?

Tags: android, eclipse, xcode, android-studio

I think assistant editor of xcode is convenient feature because it shows a layout automatically when open it's code.

Is there a this feature in eclipse adt or android studio?

========== added explanation =============

Sorry my question has not enough explanation.

Above "it's code" means implement code.
For example, activity_main.xml => it's code means "MainActivity.java"

Comment: Have you tried opening a layout file in Eclipse? The short answer is yes there is but I'm not sure it required a question when it would be quicker to simply open Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Yes. On the bottom of the `xml` editor, there is a tab labeled `Layout`:

[image: XML editor]

Note: You need to select an `xml` file in `res/layout` or `res/layout-xy`.